# How to return a function in either T or Future[T] context?

Tags: scala

Currently I have a function that takes a `contentType` and `inputObject`, and returns output depending on `contentType`, pretty standard stuff:

```
class ObjectMapper {
  def mapInputObject(contentType: String, input: InputObject): OutputObject {
    contentType match {
      case "A": mapToOutputA(input)
      case "B": mapToOutputB(input)
    }
  }

  private def mapToOutputA(input: InputObject): OutputObject = ???
  private def mapToOutputB(input: InputObject): OutputObject = ???
}
```

I guess the private functions would be better if they're separate classes instead, but anyway so far it works. However, now we have a new `contentType` that can only be map in a future:

```
def mapToOutputC(input: InputObject): Future[OutputObject] = ???
```

The caller only knows the `contentType`, it doesn't know or doesn't care whether output is immediate or in a Future, I tried to use higher-kinded types, but got stuck and not even sure if it's the correct approach:

```
object Context {
  type Id[X] = X
}
import Context.Id

trait ObjectMapperFunc[C[_]] {
  def mapFunc(input: InputObject): C[OutputObject]
}

object OutputAMapperFunc extends ObjectMapperFunc[Id] {
  override def mapFunc(input: InputObject): Id[OutputObject] = ???
}

class OutputCMapperFunc extends ObjectMapperFunc[Future] {
  override def mapSync(input: InputObject): Future[OutputObject] = ???
}

class ObjectMapper {

  def mapInputObject(contentType: String, input: InputObject): ObjectMapperFunc[_] = {
    contentType match {
      case "A": OutputAMapperFunc
      case "C": new OutputCMapperFunc
    }
  }
}
```

Code doesn't compile, it says ObjectMapperFunc[_], _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: one

What's the best way to solve this? The caller doesn't care whether it gets back the result as `Id[T]` or `Future[T]`, it just needs to get the result.

Comment: Tried to read through first few lines. `case 'A'` will never match any `String`. And `mapToOutputA(input)` is not a type. Is this even Scala?

Comment: If it makes no difference to the caller, why not just always return a `Future[T]`? Just wrap the `T` with `Future.successful` if you want to do it synchronously.